# Rails shows non existent database records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Rails shows that an instance of the `Comment` model exists, even though the database is empty. My code to show the `Comment` is

```
<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
   <%= c %>
<% end %>
```

And from that, I get `#<Comment:0x007fe971c02800>` also if i do `c.attributes` I get 
`{"id"=>nil, "body"=>nil, "author"=>nil, "post_id"=>37, "deleted"=>nil, "locked"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}`, but the table has no records. If I change that code to

```
<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
   <%= c.body %>
<% end %>
```

I get nothing.
Maybe it has something to me using [`closure_tree`](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree). 
If it helps, here is the schema for the table:

```
create_table "comment_hierarchies", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "ancestor_id",   null: false
  t.integer "descendant_id", null: false
  t.integer "generations",   null: false
end

add_index "comment_hierarchies", ["ancestor_id", "descendant_id", "generations"], name: "comment_anc_desc_udx", unique: true
add_index "comment_hierarchies", ["descendant_id"], name: "comment_desc_idx"

create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "body"
  t.string   "author"
  t.string   "post_id"
  t.boolean  "deleted"
  t.boolean  "locked"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**EDIT:** I fixed it by changing the form on the page to make a new comment from

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], :html => {:class => 'ui form'}) do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Comment", style: "max-height: 100px;"%>
          </div>
          <p>
            <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: "blue ui button" %>
          </p>
      <% end %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for([@post, Comment.new], :html => {:class => 'ui form'}) do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Comment", style: "max-height: 100px;"%>
          </div>
          <p>
            <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: "blue ui button" %>
          </p>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: what is `closure_tree` ?

Comment: Try `<%= c.inspect %>` or `<%= c.attributes %>` to see if the Comment returned is a built Comment for a form (no `id` value) or if it is actually persisted in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you be calling `@post.comments.new` somewhere before this to render the comment form? This could be adding the new, non-persisted record in the `association_cache`.

To avoid this, you should be able to instantiate the comment as `Comment.new(post_id: @post.id)`. This shouldn't add the comment to the association_cache. If it does, you really don't need the `post_id` on the new `Comment`. You probably have it in a hidden field anyway.

Comment: Thanks, dude. If I remove a form to add a new comment that I put before the list of comments, it works fine. Any ideas on how to get it to work with the form?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there **is** a comment persisted in your database for this post.

`c.body` may return nil, it alone doesn't define that there is no comment record in your database. Maybe you had no validation or manually skipped it on the console a while ago.

`c.inspect` will give you a more verbose breakdown of what data is in the object.

How are you confirming your database is empty? Does `@post.comments.count` equal 0?